# How can I have a condition in a cond/if clause regarding length of a list without using the length function?

Tags: scheme, racket

In class, we're instructed to not use the length function when it doesn't need to be used. I know how to make a function that counts the length of a list, but I wanna know how to put length as a criteria in a cond or if without using length.

I have:

```
(define (thing ls)
  (if (> (length ls) 10)
      'p
      'q))

(define (thing2 ls)
  (cond
    [(> (add1 (thing2 (rest ls))) 10) 'p]
    [else 'q]))
```

The bottom one gives me: "rest: expects a non-empty list; given: '()"

How can I do this?

Comment: we haven't gotten to cdr in class. Is there a way to make `thing2` work like `thing` or is it not possible?

Comment: You never check whether `ls` is empty before evaluating `(rest ls)`.  (It's not very common for "real-world" Scheme code to depend on a list's length. Usually you write your code around the structure of a list rather than its size. )

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by passing as a parameter the minimum number of elements that you need to encounter before being able to answer `'p`. Notice that the first base case prevents that we go off the list:

```
(define (thing ls n)
  (cond [(empty? ls) 'q]
        [(zero? n)   'p]
        [else (thing (rest ls) (sub1 n))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(thing '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) 10)
=> 'q
(thing '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11) 10)
=> 'p
```